# Vue create application gives /bin/sh: pnpm: command not found

Tags: node.js, vue.js, npm, webstorm

Somehow something broke on my computer and Vue cli gives me strange

```
/bin/sh: pnpm: command not found
```

after I execute `vue create application` while script continue running, this makes WebStorm create new project for Vue to fail.

[image]

Kind of wired because everything worked until I uninstalled node by home-brew and reinstalled it again. Now I tried also to install node by binary package but still this problem persist.

Tried to start frontend JS development and I have this while following official ways, I cannot lose this feelings how this node npm JavaScript ecosystem is fragile compared to native mobile apps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok I found it by trial and error...  I found in some js that there actually exists some `pnpm` package I installed it `npm install -g pnpm` and problem went away.